# waiting for requestAnimationFrame to finish (via callbacks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, requestanimationframe, pixi.js

So I'm new here, apologies if this is a basic question but I can't see it answered anywhere else.

I'm trying to write a webapp which shows an animation (using pixijs), and afterwards displays a div requesting a response. My issue is that because the animation is handled using **requestAnimationFrame** the animation occurs asynchronously, and so the response and animation phases occur simultaneously (the div appears instantly and obscures the animation).

Now I've looked around and the consensus seems to be to use a callback function, which only gets triggered after all the asynchronous work has been performed, allowing that serial progression.

HOWEVER, requestAnimationFrame takes the form

***requestAnimationFrame(update_screen_objects)***,

but breaks when I try to do:

requestAnimationFrame(update_screen_objects(***response_phase_callback***))

as clearly requestAnimationFrame doesn't like being passed a function that itself has a callback. So my question is: what should I do to the animation loop to ensure that subsequent functions execute AFTER the animation is complete?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is an example of the code in the above form that *doesn't* work.

```
function animate(callback) {

var finished = false;

if ((new Date().getTime()) < adaptTime){
    runFlicker(false);
} else if ((new Date().getTime()) < judgeTime){
    hideAdaptors();
} else if ((new Date().getTime()) > judgeTime){
    stage.visible = false;          
    finished = true;                
}
renderer.render(stage);

if (!finished){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate(callback) ); //Ensures it will keep looping
    //requestAnimationFrame(animate); //This does work, but my issue still persists
} else {
    callback(); //By the time callback() is required, you can't access it as requestAnimationFrame doesn't accept animate() with a function passed to it.
} 
}
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` won't pass arguments to the function

Comment: Your second attempt *calls* the function, instead of *passing it*. Instead, pass a function expression that calls the `update_screen_objects` function and passes your callback.

Comment: Can we have an example of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. You basically need to generate that step (`animate`) function with the callback, instead of passing in the results of your call to `animate`, which would be `undefined`.

```
function generateAnimation(callback) {

  function step() {

    var finished = false;
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();

    if (now < adaptTime) {
      runFlicker(false);
    } else if (now < judgeTime) {
      hideAdaptors();
    } else if (now > judgeTime) {
      stage.visible = false;
      finished = true;
    }

    renderer.render(stage);

    if (!finished) {
      requestAnimationFrame(step);
    } else {
      callback();
    }

  }

  return step;

}

// Usage:
requestAnimationFrame(generateAnimation(callback));
```

Comment: Thanks dude! So just to fully understand whats going on here, using the wrapper function generateAnimation(callback), its allowing both step() and the callback function to still be within scope?

Comment: Correct. Basically, to reword my answer, what you wanted wants to have a version of `step` that calls `callback` that you can pass to rAF, not to call `step` with `callback` and pass the result of that call to rAF.

Comment: This is very inefficient, you should use @NickSweeting's answer instead

Answer (score 2):

No need for a complex wrapper, just do:

```
requestAnimationFrame(update_screen_objects.bind(window, response_phase_callback))
```

This "[currys](http://kishorelive.com/2012/02/06/currying-in-javascript-using-bind/)" the update_screen_objects function by partially applying some arguments.  The result of .bind(context, arg1) is a function that when called, only takes any arguments that aren't already bound, e.g arg2, arg3, etc.